# html: fixed footer shouldn't overlap width the scrolling main div

Tags: html, css

I have this html:

```
<div class="main">text...</div>
<div class="footer">footer...</div>
```

and the style:

```
.main {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
.footer {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

The problem is that the main scrolls across the footer too, but I wish that should end before the footer, how I can do that?
thanks

Comment: you can share your code if that didn't help you because every problem has a lot of reasons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the footer in a div and giv it a height and width and fix it position also you can add a margin in the main div (height than the footer height) to prevent it to across the footer if that didn't work;

```css
.footer{
height:/*your height */;
width:100%;
bottom:0;
position:fixed;
margin:auto;}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
<footer></footer>
</div>
```